# graphql - TypeError: graphql_1.getIntrospectionQuery is not a function

Tags: graphql

After installing `merge-graphql-schemas` I attached these code in my `server.js`

```
const typeDefs = mergeTypes(fileLoader(path.join(__dirname, './schema')), { all: true });
const resolvers = mergeResolvers(fileLoader(path.join(__dirname, ".resolvers")));
```

I get an error like this

```
var parsedIntrospectionQuery = graphql_1.parse(graphql_1.getIntrospectionQuery());
                                                         ^

**TypeError: graphql_1.getIntrospectionQuery is not a function**
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\My_WorkSpace\node\eticket-backend\node_modules\graphql-tools-fork\src\stitch\introspectSchema.ts:15:54)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (E:\My_WorkSpace\node\eticket-backend\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\My_WorkSpace\node\eticket-backend\node_modules\graphql-tools-fork\src\stitch\index.ts:448:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: What version of `graphql` are you using? That function was added in a more recent version.

Comment: How the problem was solved ? Can you answer your question with some explanation so that other people can get help ?